# Найти в файле строки где нет двухзначных чисел

Tags: поиск, числа, python-3.6

Помогите написать программу, которая находит в файле сроки где нет двухзначных чисел.

Comment: Как вариант для валидации строк можно использовать регулярное выражение типа \d\.\d

Comment: @user287120      `a_list = re.findall('\d\.\d-', a)` я сделал вот так. но у меня выводит пустота

Comment: Зачем символ '-' в конце регулярки. '\d\.\d' соответствет строке типа '34343.656'. Если в строке только цифры то можно ^\d+\.\d+$

Comment: А есть ли другие варианты кроме регулярных выражений? Например через цикл. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: С python-3.6 не работаю, поэтому извините, в этом я вам не помошник. Но уверен, что вы где-то не так используете поиск по регулярке, все должно работать. Конечно можно и циклом, к примеру, разбиваем строку на массив, итерируемся по нем и пошагово сверяем. Но такой метод куда менее эфективен, но более консервативен ;)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отсеять строки, в которых больше одной цифры подряд:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput 
from itertools import filterfalse

lines = filterfalse(re.compile(r'\d\d').search,
                    fileinput.input())
sys.stdout.writelines(lines)
```

Пример использования:

```
$ no-dd-lines input.txt
```

Если трёхзначные (и более) числа разрешены, то можно `r'\b\d\d\b'` regex попробовать (не разрешать только строки, в которых две цифры отдельное слово образуют).

Answer (score -1):

я не имею представления кактой файл ты используешь: .txt, .csv, .xlsx...
для .txt без регулярок я могу предложить такой черновой вариант:

```
f = open('1.txt', 'r')
for i in f:
   i = str.replace(i ,'\n','')
   line = str.split(i, ' ')
   for j in line:
      print (len(j))
f.close
```

но тебе нужно будет указать разделитель между цыфрами:

```
 line = str.split(i, ' ')
```

и додумать как ты хочешь отображать строки, какие проверки дальше делать. я тебе для скорости дальнейшей обработки вывожу просто длину каждого числа\строки:

```
print (len(j))
```

так что дерзай дальше

Comment: не вижу какое отношение этот ответ имеет к вопросу: найти строки без двухзначных чисел.

Comment: простите, не указано какой тип файла используется. не указан пример записей в файле. потому считаю относящимся к заданиям учебных заведений. я тоже своим судентам даю такое задание когда проходят работу с файлами. так же хочу заметить что все начинающие делают одну и ту же ошибку при роботе с текстовым полем и текстовым файлом - само название говорит о том, что в них храится текст, даже если это число, оно всё равно текст. а данный код помогает отследить длину каждого слова и как результат этот код можно модернизировать исходя из конкретных условий и додумать логику, так как задача на логику